# Print data of any type aligned

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm a beginner in C++. While searching for a function which could help print any data type, I have found this template:

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::stringstream out;

    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << std::setw(15) << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };

    OutputDebugStringA(out.str().c_str());
}

doPrint("TEST",
    "\nname:", "Louis", "Elizabeth", "Charles Von Mayer", "Nar",        
    "\nx:", 10000, "y:", 200000000, "w:", 300, "h:", 4000000000000000,
    "\ncolor:", "orange", "blue", "green");
```

I would like to request help in editing this function to print the data aligned, so it could be easier to read/understand.

At the moment, this is how the data is printed to Visual Studio's output:

```
TEST         
name:          Louis      ElizabethCharles Von Mayer            Nar            
x:          10000             y:      200000000             w:            300             h:4000000000000000        
color:         orange           blue          green
```

I was trying to format the data one under another, something like this:

[image: Formated]

```
TEST
name:          Louis          Elizabeth      Charles Von Mayer             Nar            x:             10000          y:            200000000      w:             300            h:             4000000000000000              color:         orange         blue           green
```

I tried to use `setw()`, but it breaks the indentation in case the strings have different lengths.

While searching for a similar question, do I need to loop between all of the values and calculate the biggest length, and then append the spaces according to that?

Comment: Formatted width for strings will right-justify them by default. Try setting up your stream like this: `out << std::left << std::forward<Arg>(arg);`

Comment: NOte: in C++17, you might directly write `((out << std::setw(15) << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);`

Comment: @Jarod42 its in the link of the picture `Formated`, i post as picture because when i copy past it break indentation

Comment: @paddy using std::left << std::setw(15) its until unaligned https://i.imgur.com/gSzSEFg.png

Comment: Note: you don't have break line (`\n`/`std::endl`), so wrapping, if any will depend of the terminal console)

Comment: @Vitor You are not using a fixed-width font in your console. C++ stream alignment using `setw()` expects characters to be rendered with the same pixel width to appear the way you want. Otherwise, if you want to use a variable-width font, you will have to calculate each character's actual width in that font and insert the appropriate spacing into the stream as needed, but even that is not guaranteed to line things up exactly perfect. Hence, use a fixed-width font instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hello, can you tell me a font name in which could be as you described?

Comment: @Vitor there should be a multitude of fixed-width (Monospace) fonts installed with the OS, such as Consolas, Courier New, Cascadia, Lucida, etc